# amp-form error Trust for 'submit' (2) insufficient (min: 3).​

Tags: amp-html

I dont edit code.
Can't send it suddenly since yesterday.
Amp-html Update trust levels for existing actions to spec

```
<form id="myform" class="p3 hide-inputs" method="post" action-xhr="/vote" target="_blank">
<label class="ampstart-btn vote">
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="up" on="change:myform.submit">GOOD 1</label>
<label class="ampstart-btn vote">
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="down" on="change:myform.submit">BAD 0</label>
</form>

> error.js:151 Trust for 'submit' (2) insufficient (min: 3).​​​
> Ud    @   error.js:151 f.error    @   log.js:214
> Hg.satisfiesTrust @   action-impl.js:164 Ug   @   action-impl.js:502
> f.trigger @   action-impl.js:435 (anonymous)  @   action-impl.js:259
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in html page. One error is the following:

```
"action-xhr" "must start with "https://" or "//" or be relative and served from either https or from localhost. Invalid value:" "/vote"
```

so, try to change `action-xhr="/vote"` in `action-xhr="//www.yoursite.com/vote"`